# Mathematica - DSolve spits out #1 in output

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm not quite certain how to go about interpreting this.

I'm solving a fairly large system of differential equations, DSolve *sometimes* spits out a list of replacement rules that include terms that have a `#1` . I know that `#1` is a placeholder for an argument, but I just have no clue where it comes from.

If I have a system of equations similar to

```
eqs = {
x1'[t] = a1*x1[t] + b1*y1[t]
x2'[t] = a2*x2[t] + b2*y2[t]
...
y1'[t] = c1*y1[t] + d1*x1[t]
y2'[t] = c2*y2[t] + d2*x2[t]}
```

`DSolve[eqs,vars,t]` spits out something like

```
x1 -> e^(-ta1)
x2 -> e^(-t)RootSum[a1a2+a3b4#1 + a3a1b2#1]
...
```

Obviously a little more complicated but you get the point.

Nothing in the documentation hints as to why this is occurring, And it only happens under certain permuations of parameters (e.g. when I play around with parameters in the original system it either works or doesn't)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This `RootSum` may be generated by `Integrate`, which is used by `DSolve` internally, like so:

```
In[511]:= Integrate[1/(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4), x]

Out[511]= RootSum[1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + #1^4 &, 
 Log[x - #1]/(1 + 2 #1 + 3 #1^2 + 4 #1^3) &]
```

It represents a symbolic expression that is the `Sum[ Log[x-t]/(1+2*t+3 t^2+4 t^3), {t, {"roots of 1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4"}]` (caution, invalid syntax intentional). You can recover the expected normal form using `Normal`:

```
In[512]:= Normal[%]

Out[512]= 
Log[(-1)^(1/5) + x]/(1 - 2 (-1)^(1/5) + 3 (-1)^(2/5) - 4 (-1)^(3/5)) +
  Log[-(-1)^(2/5) + x]/(
 1 - 4 (-1)^(1/5) + 2 (-1)^(2/5) + 3 (-1)^(4/5)) + 
 Log[(-1)^(3/5) + x]/(
 1 - 3 (-1)^(1/5) - 2 (-1)^(3/5) + 4 (-1)^(4/5)) + 
 Log[-(-1)^(4/5) + x]/(1 + 4 (-1)^(2/5) - 3 (-1)^(3/5) + 2 (-1)^(4/5))
```

Or using the `Sum` directly:

```
In[513]:= Sum[
 Log[x - t]/(1 + 2*t + 3 t^2 + 4 t^3), {t, 
  t /. {ToRules[Roots[1 + t + t^2 + t^3 + t^4 == 0, t]]}}]

Out[513]= 
Log[(-1)^(1/5) + x]/(1 - 2 (-1)^(1/5) + 3 (-1)^(2/5) - 4 (-1)^(3/5)) +
  Log[-(-1)^(2/5) + x]/(
 1 - 4 (-1)^(1/5) + 2 (-1)^(2/5) + 3 (-1)^(4/5)) + 
 Log[(-1)^(3/5) + x]/(
 1 - 3 (-1)^(1/5) - 2 (-1)^(3/5) + 4 (-1)^(4/5)) + 
 Log[-(-1)^(4/5) + x]/(1 + 4 (-1)^(2/5) - 3 (-1)^(3/5) + 2 (-1)^(4/5))

In[514]:= % - %% // FullSimplify

Out[514]= 0
```

Comment: `Normal` Solved the `#1`'s in `RootSum` however there are still stray ones around.

Comment: @crasic I guess the point is that `RootSum` is a good expression, and you should not try to get rid of it. Compare `Integrate[1/(1 + 2 x + x^7), x]` to `Integrate[1/(1 + 2 x + x^7), x]//Normal`. It should possible to resolve any `RootSum` into explicit sum using `Normal`. If you can not do it for some, could you please post the stubborn `RootSum` expression ?

Comment: All the RootSum components can be eradicated, but there may of necessity remain Root objects which use #.